# Generic class with generic arraylist

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

Hoping I can get some help on this. I'm trying to instantiate a generic object Student with a generic arrayList as a list of grades. I can't get my Add method to work properly. I keep getting a null pointer exception- which is obvious as it is initialized to null- just not sure what is wrong with my add method. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, the requirements of this assignment are very strict- I have to do it this way. Thanks.

I have two classes: the first, Student:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student <S>{

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<S> grades;



    private double average;


    // the constructor
    public Student (String studentName, ArrayList<S> studentGrades){
        name = studentName;
        grades = studentGrades;
    }

    // get the name
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    //set the name
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // add a grade to the array
    public void addGrade(S n){

        grades.add(n);

    }

    // return a grade from the array. This will be used for the calculation.
    public S getGrade(int n){

        return grades.get(n);


    }

    // compute the average grade for each student
    public double computeAverage(){

        Double sum = 0.00;
        for(S grade : grades){ 

            if (grade instanceof Double){
            sum += (Double)grade;
            }
            if (grade instanceof Integer){
                sum += (Integer)grade;
            }
        }
        average = sum.doubleValue()/ grades.size();
        return average;

    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name + "'s average grade is " + average;
    }
}
```

And the second, test:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // create the studentList array
        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        HashMap<String, Student> studentMap = new HashMap<String, Student>();

        // the values for math.random to create the grades
        int min = 0;
        int max = 100;
        double dmin = 0.00;
        double dmax = 100.00;

        // initialize the variables

        ArrayList grades = null;

        //------------------------------------
        // Create the students (the method signature is wrong. It blows up regardless of what I try to add.)
        Student<Integer> Fred = new Student<Integer>("Fred", grades);   
        //null pointer exception. Also points to the add method in the student class.

        //-------------------------------------

        Student<Integer> Wilma = new Student<Integer>("Wilma", grades);
        Student<Double> Barney = new Student<Double>("Barney", grades);
        Student<Double> Betty = new Student<Double>("Betty", grades);   

        // add the random grades 
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            Fred.addGrade((int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            Wilma.addGrade((int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            Barney.addGrade((double) (Math.random() * (dmax - dmin) + dmin));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            Betty.addGrade((double) (Math.random() * (dmax - dmin) + dmin));
        }
        // add the students to the array list
        studentList.add(Fred);
        studentList.add(Wilma);
        studentList.add(Barney);
        studentList.add(Betty);

        studentMap.put(Fred.getName(), Fred);
        studentMap.put(Wilma.getName(), Wilma);
        studentMap.put(Barney.getName(), Barney);
        studentMap.put(Betty.getName(), Betty);


        //iterate through the list & print to the console
        Iterator<Student> itr = studentList.iterator();{
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(itr.next().<Student>toString());

                //Initialize the array to hold the key variables
                Set<String> mapKeys = studentMap.keySet();
                //mapKeys.add(something);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create a new ArrayList.

Comment: Why did you make `Student` class generic at all? I don't see any need.

Comment: It is required by the assignment.

Comment: Thank you all for the help- I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing on Test the Grades as null

```
ArrayList grades = null;
```

and when you try to add a grade with

```
Fred.addGrade(...);
```

the internal code in Student does

```
grades.add(n);
```

But grades is initialized to null creating a Null Exception.

Initialize the grades with the proper type.

Example:

```
Student<Integer> Wilma = new Student<Integer>("Wilma", new ArrayList<Integer>());
Student<Double> Barney = new Student<Double>("Barney", new ArrayList<Double>());
Student<Double> Betty = new Student<Double>("Betty", new ArrayList<Double>());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the ArrayList grades. Currently you are passing a null value. Do the following in that line:

```
ArrayList grades = new ArrayList();
```

A good practice would be to use generics while initializing the ArrayList but since your grades seem to be of differing types, I'm skipping it out.

Answer (score 1):

In your Test class you have 
`ArrayList grades = null;` - you need to create the grades ArrayList and fill it with data before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public class Student<S>
{
    // declare array
    private final ArrayList<S> grades = new ArrayList<S>();
    private String name;

    // One arg constructor
    public Student(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Two arg constructor
    public Student(String name, ArrayList<S> grades)
    {
        this(name);
        this.grades.addAll(grades);
    }

    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code in the following manner in Test class:

```
 Student<Integer> Fred = new Student<Integer>("Fred", new ArrayList<Integer>());   
    //null pointer exception. Also points to the add method in the student class.

    //-------------------------------------

 Student<Integer> Wilma = new Student<Integer>("Wilma", new ArrayList<Integer>());
 Student<Double> Barney = new Student<Double>("Barney", new ArrayList<Double>());
 Student<Double> Betty = new Student<Double>("Betty", new ArrayList<Double>());
```

Hope, this will help.